# Repeating alarm manager won't stop

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to stop a repeating alarm but it doesn't work.

Here is the code to stop alarm :

```
 Intent intentstop = new Intent(context, ReceiverAssign.class);
                PendingIntent senderstop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                        0, intentstop, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManagerstop = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManagerstop.cancel(senderstop);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!